# Is there even a simpler way to express anonymous classes in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I translated this Java

```
new Thread("Cute Thread") {
  public void run() {
    int a = 3;
  }
}.start();
```

to this Kotlin

```
object : Thread("Cute Thread") {
  override fun run() {
     val a = 3
  }
}.start()
```

But I feel that there is a simpler way of doing this, however I can't find any examples.

I've tried

```
  Thread("Cute Thread") { val a = 3 }.start()
```

But with no success...

PS. I know that starting a Thread like this is a bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue here is that the `Thread` class constructor has parameters in a bad order for Kotlin.  For `Runnable` you can easily use a [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) (*a single method interface can be treated as a lambda*) but because the lambda is not the last parameter it looks kinda clunky.  In the case where there is only one parameter it is fine:

```
Thread { val a = 3 }.start()
```

However with more than one parameter, they are backwards causing this uglier syntax with the lambda as a parameter inside the parenthesis:

```
Thread({ val a = 3 }, "some name").start()
```

**Instead you should use the Kotlin stdlib function [`thread()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/thread.html)**

With that function you have simpler syntax of:

```
// create thread, auto start it, runs lambda in thread
thread { val a = 3 }  

// create thread with given name, auto start it, runs lambda in thread
thread(name = "Cute Thread") { val a = 3 }  

// creates thread that is paused, with a lambda to run later
thread(false) { val a = 3 } 

// creates thread that is paused with a given name, with a lambda to run later
thread(false, name = "Cute Thread") { val a = 3 }
```

See also: [`thread()` function documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/thread.html)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @PedroD answer has been modernized

Comment: This is nice for `thread` as it already exists, but how can I create my own implementation that will allow a shorter version too?  For example some simple interface as `interface OnResultCallback{
    fun onSuccess(result: SomeResultClass)
}`

Comment: @androiddeveloper please create a new question as yours is not related to this specific question.  Also see "SAM conversion for Kotlin interfaces" in latest Kotlin releases.

Comment: @JaysonMinard I don't remember why I asked this, but the answer is "fun interface", I think.

Answer (score 6):

There's no different way to implement an anonymous class (except [SAM conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html)).
But you can still simplify your code by:

```
 Thread({ val a = 3 }).start()
```

or with thread name:

```
Thread({ val a = 3 }, "Cute Thread").start()
```

Comment: You're not providing a solution to the problem (anonymous class syntax), but rather a different way to use the `Thread` class.

Comment: @nhaarman are you sure his problem is about shorter anonymous classes or rather shorter code in general? If you're a subject purist you're right but if take an effort to understand his real intention you might be wrong: `But I feel that there is a simpler way of doing this, however I can't find any examples.`

Comment: Yes, my goal was to make the code shorter, thanks! Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question. I am all for less code, as long as it doesn't affect readability. That was the main reason for me to go from Java to Kotlin.

Comment: @PedroD You were talking about `PS. I know that starting a Thread like this is a bad practice`. This answer overcomes the bad practice, you're not inheriting from `Thread` anymore, but rather passing a `Runnable` to the constructor.

Comment: Is inheriting from `Thread` is also considered a bad practice? The bad practice I was referring to was creating a headless thread. I.e. I will have no control for this thread's life-cycle from that moment on, because I have no references to it. By the book, I should keep a list of all my threads.

Comment: @nhaarman did you change your mind about a usability of this answer? :)

Comment: Ah, sure. I can't undo the down vote though until you make an edit ;)

Comment: There is another way to implement an anonymous class, this is misleading because it does not consider SAM conversions.

Answer (score 2):

You code is absolutely correct. The only way to simplify it is it extract the logic into a function and then reuse it:

```
fun newThread(name: String, block: () -> Unit): Thread {
    return object : Thread(name) {
        override fun run() = block()
    }.start()
}
```

Usage:

```
newThread("Cute Thread") {
    val a = 3
}
```

Comment: And if you're about to write such function, there's already one at your disposal in stdlib: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/thread.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extend/implement some class/interface in your anonymous class there is no other way than:

```
object: Thread("Name"){
    //...
}.start()
```

The simplest possible construction is of course:

```
val adhoc = object{
    // some code here
}
```

but there are no simpler way to do this.

[Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html), but You probably read that.